# Change default file descriptor for Rust print functions

Tags: rust, stdout, ffi, libc, unsafe

I'm working on Rust and using a shared library written in C++. The problem that the C++ library spawns a few threads that constantly print to stdout (1) and that interferes with my own logging.
I was able to duplicate stdout using [dup](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.86/libc/fn.dup.html) to fd = 3. Then I open up a pipe (4, 5), and use dup2 to
move old stdout to one end of the pipe.
As a result:

- C++ library writes to fd = 1 (old stdout), but that goes to another pipe where I can capture the data in another thread (say I read from fd = 5). Then I can parse those logs and print them to the console.
- In Rust code I can use [libc::write](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.86/libc/fn.write.html) to fd = 3 and that will go directly to the console.

The problem now is that standard Rust function such as println! will still try to write to fd = 1, but I'd like to be able to change the default behavior so Rust code will write to fd = 3 instead of 1, that way, any Rust print related function will print to the console, and everything from the shared library will be parsed on a separate thread.

Is that possible to do in stable Rust? Closest thing I found is [set_print](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31343) function which looks like it's unstable and I couldn't even use it using +nightly build.

Comment: Probably don't need the `c++` tag, since this is a Rust question and C++ is only tangentially involved.

Comment: The safest bet is probably to make your own custom `println` macro that simply redirects the args to a `format` macro call.

Comment: @Aplet123, indeed, that's what I'm doing right now. Using an appender with a writer on top of  [log4rs](https://docs.rs/log4rs/1.0.0/log4rs/) so log! macros will write to a different fd than stdout. But it will be much easier to simply change the stdout.

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable to use [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) instead of `println!`, you can call [`from_raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html) to open a proper `File`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;

let mut out = BufWriter::new(unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(3) });
writeln!(out, "hello world!")?;
// ...
```

Note: `from_raw_fd` is unsafe because you must ensure that the `File` assumes sole ownership of the file descriptor, in this case that no one else closes or interacts with file descriptor 3. (But you can use [`into_raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.IntoRawFd.html#tymethod.into_raw_fd) to re-assert ownership of the fd it while consuming the `File`.)